# Mudblazor: How to add child div to main div on button click

Tags: c#, html, .net-6.0, mudblazor

I am not much familiar with Javascript. I am working on a Mudblazor project. All the Backend and Frontend logic is implemented using c#. I have main div which displays several MudTextFields in one child div (Div1) and after this div there is another child div (Div2) which displays MudSelect associated with MudTextField. Please see the image below.
[image]

You can see in Picture two child divs Div1 and Div2. I want that when Add Div MudButton is clicked than a new row should be added into Div2 so that I could select new MudSelectItem from MudSelect and enter it's value into MudTextField. Please guide me how can I implement this requirement.
I will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created sub models within main model. And on button click I add new sub model into main and it is displayed on the razor page successfully.